# Can you set Postfix to enforce TLS on incoming email only from certain domains or IPs?

Tags: postfix

I'm looking for a Postfix configuration option like `smtpd_enforce_tls` but one that lets me enforce TLS selectively, depending on what domain the email is coming in from. I need to allow non-TLS incoming email from all but certain selected originating domains.

Is this possible? I know that it's simple to selectively enforce TLS on email going *out* from Postfix, but I'm talking about email coming in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can - with a little engineering :)

Since you say you want to enforce TLS based on sender domain, you add a check_sender_access restriction to your smtpd_sender_restrictions, like so:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/enforced_tls
```

and in `/etc/postfix/enforced_tls`:

```
@example.org   reject_plaintext_session
@example.net   reject_plaintext_session
```

Don't forget to postmap the file, and reload postfix when you're done.

Comment: The domain names should not start with a `@` as caught by @Georgi.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/postfix/enforced_tls` must be in this format:

```
example.org   reject_plaintext_session
example.net   reject_plaintext_session
```

refer to http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html

Answer (score 0):

I would even suggest a more restrictive version by also requiring a valid certificate from the sending server like this:

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
...
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/enfoced_tls
...
```

`/etc/postfix/enforced_tls`:

```
example.org     reject_plaintext_session, permit_tls_all_clientcerts, reject
example.net     reject_plaintext_session, permit_tls_all_clientcerts, reject
```

This should also reject the session when the certificate of the connecting server cannot be validated via the CAs in `smtpd_tls_CAfile`, which in this case can safely contain the system default CAs. Please correct me if I'm mistaken here.