# How do you configure postfix to only try unencrypted email with a fix list of IP address/domains?

Tags: postfix, tls, pci-dss

A PCI scan told me to stop using TLS 1.0 for e-mail.  I'm using postfix, so I disabled TLS 1.0, and all traffic for 1.0 stopped.  Then the next day I looked at the logs and I see a lot of this...

```
connect from 66-220-155-139.outmail.facebook.com[66.220.155.139]
SSL_accept error from 66-220-155-139.outmail.facebook.com[66.220.155.139]: -1
warning: TLS library problem: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:640:
lost connection after STARTTLS from 66-220-155-139.outmail.facebook.com[66.220.155.139]
disconnect from 66-220-155-139.outmail.facebook.com[66.220.155.139]
```

I contacted a few of the admin of the servers.  Turns our we are both using opportunistic TLS, but we don't have a common TLS protocal, they support 1.0 and I support 1.2.  After a bit of googleing I think the problem is a failure to fail back to unencrypted after trying to negotiate TLS unsuccessfully.

So my question is.  How do you configure postfix to only try unencrypted email with a fix list of IP address/domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it working, with a 2nd server.

```
server1 {only TLS 1.2}  DNS of MX value 30
server2 {TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2} DNS of MX value 35

Internet -->  Firewall(allow list of DNS email servers to server2) 
    --TLS(1.0)-> server2 --(with TLS1.2)-> server1
```

Check logs of server1 to get list of servers that need a firewall rule.

This method will hopefully allow me to control PCI junk better in the future.

===EDIT===

After about a mouth I can tell you trying to disable TLS 1.0 is difficult.  I have been writing about 4 to 5 exceptions a day.  Most are for banks, and financial related e-mail server.  Also yahoo.com and paypal.com will not work with this solution they only try the first MX never the 2nd.  I going to ask for an exception and look into running my spam filter in the cloud, so my e-mail server only had to accept mail from that cloud spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing email, you can configure the TLS policy table in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. Check [this official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_policy) for more details and some examples.

For inbound email, please use combination of `smtpd_sender_restriction` and `reject_plaintext_session` as explained in [these answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/389636/can-you-set-postfix-to-enforce-tls-on-incoming-email-only-from-certain-domains-o).

Comment: dose that work with inbound e-mail?  The outbound e-mail works fine.

Comment: yes by smtpd_sender_restrictions check: http://serverfault.com/questions/389636/can-you-set-postfix-to-enforce-tls-on-incoming-email-only-from-certain-domains-o